# Issue in Spark + kafka Integration

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading a CSV file through DataSet and then sending that file to Kafka. spark-submit job is working fine but when the program sends files to Kafka it gives me an exception. Below is the exception -

> FileStreamSource
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:297)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:193)
>   Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'value' not found;
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:72)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:72)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.validateQuery(KafkaWriter.scala:71)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.write(KafkaWriter.scala:87)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSink.addBatch(KafkaSink.scala:38)

Below is my code:

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop-2.7.3\\");
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);

 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
          .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "D:\\Workspac\\checkpoint")
          .appName("StructuredStreamingAverage")
          .master("local")
          .getOrCreate();



StructType userSchema = new StructType().add("startdate", "string").add("accountname", "string").add("eventdate", "string")/*.add("u_lastlogin", "string")*//*.add("u_firstName", "string")*/;

Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.
        readStream()
        .option("header",true)
        .option("sep",",")
        .schema(userSchema)
        .csv("D:\\Workspac\\sophos");

Dataset<Row> df_DateConverted = dataset.withColumn("eventdate", from_unixtime(col("eventdate").divide(1000)).cast(DataTypes.TimestampType));



if(df_DateConverted.isStreaming()) {
    try {
        df_DateConverted
          .select("CAST(key AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
          .writeStream()
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
          .option("topic", "rawEventTopic")
          .start().awaitTermination();
    } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As exception cleary says that

> **Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'value' not found;**

So may be the issue is with `.select("CAST(key AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")` code but I dont know what I should write here. Thanks.

I tried with

```
    df_DateConverted
           .select(col("key").cast("string"), from_json(col("value").cast("string"),userSchema))
          .writeStream()
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
          .option("topic", "rawEventTopic")
          .start().awaitTermination();
```

but facing below exception -

```html
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`key`' given input columns: [startdate, accountname, eventdate];;
'Project [unresolvedalias(cast('key as string), None), jsontostructs(StructField(startdate,StringType,true), StructField(accountname,StringType,true), StructField(eventdate,StringType,true), cast('value as string), Some(UTC)) AS jsontostructs(CAST(value AS STRING))#10]
+- StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@5f3ddc86,csv,List(),Some(StructType(StructField(startdate,StringType,true), StructField(accountname,StringType,true), StructField(eventdate,StringType,true))),List(),None,Map(sep -> ,, header -> true, path -> D:\cybernetizWorkspace\sophos),None), FileSource[D:\cybernetizWorkspace\sophos], [startdate#0, accountname#1, eventdate#2]
```

Output of **df_DateConverted.printSchema();** is below -

```
root
 |-- startdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- accountname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eventdate: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `df_DateConverted`? Why are you checking out whether it's streaming or not since it is a streaming dataset? Can you `dataset.printSchema` and add the output to the question? Thanks.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I have updated my question with the output of df_DateConverted.printSchema(). Actually in csv file there is a column which contain date in long format. So df_DateConverted dataset we are converting unix time to timestamp datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from `df_DateConverted` schema you don't have a key column and hence the error when doing `col("key").cast("string")`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`key`' given input columns: [startdate, accountname, eventdate];;
```

You can simply remove the key while writing the data to kafka because `key` is optional while writing data to kafka. refer: [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka)

In your above implementation the syntax `"to_json(struct(*)) AS value"` is wrong and hence you are getting an error on `value`.

You should do something like:

```
df_DateConverted
          .select(to_json(struct($"startdate", $"accountname", $"eventdate")).alias("value"))
          .writeStream()
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
          .option("topic", "rawEventTopic")
          .start().awaitTermination();
```